# Where to find Microsoft Project interop tutorial or  File Format Specification?

Tags: .net, office-interop, ms-project

Anyone got a good tutorial for Microsoft Project interop (preferrably in C# or F#) or documentation and explanation of the file format used?

Context:
I'm trying to bridge the gap between a planning tool and Microsoft Project and basically just want to transform the format used by the planning tool into the file format used by Microsoft Project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in working with the file formats which can be consumed by Microsoft Project, you may find [MPXJ](http://mpxj.sf.net) useful.

I'd be interested in hearing about the planning package you are exporting data from as I'm gradually extending the range of data sources supported by MPXJ (including Planner, Primavera, and so on).

Cheers!

Jon

Comment: It seems to be what I'm looking for. The planning tool I'm exporting from is one we've build and the only format that will be exported seems to be MPX files :)

Answer (score 0):

When I did such thing, I used COM to access the file - it has very logical structure, I was even able to write into it without any problems.  So my advice is to use COM or native MS Project API if it exists.

Alternative would be to store data into MSSQL, but as I remember the format there is a real pain.

Also: Please note that MS Project doesn't have the ability to modify the file transitionally - even when it's stored into the database.  So you won't be able to add task (for example) without loading the whole file into memory, doing what you need, and saving it back.

At least that was the state of the affairs back in 200x